# Not able to display the value within the input field

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an input field and I would like to place a default value. This is how I tried it:

```html
<input matInput formControlName="name" value="Ray">
```

The value is not getting displayed. See my code on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uql3rs-5b88aa?file=src/app/dialog-overview-example.html).

Comment: Your value is empty in your ts file. That's where you need to put a default or patch value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input is bind to a `FormControl`, so just set `"Ray"` value in your `"name"` form control and remove `value="Ray"` in your template :

```
<input matInput formControlName="name">


formMain = this._fb.group({
   name: ['Ray', Validators.required],
});
```

Answer (score 1):

On `DialogOverviewExample`, the formControl must have a value. If you put it like this:

```
  formMain = this._fb.group({
    name: ['myName', Validators.required],
  });
```

"myName" will be displayed on the input.